# rails - problem starting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to start the server on a rails app. with some apps it works fine, others I get this message:

```
rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository

Runtime options:
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to run Rails 2.x applications with this command. It will fail with this message. Since its consistently failing on certain apps, check if they are rails 2.x apps.

You can only run Rails 3.x applications with this command.

Answer (score 1):

You must be missing `script/rails` file.  Maybe you removed it by accident, or did something wrong while upgrading from Rails 2.  Just copy it from a working project (or a new one).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are including a character after the 's'. If you type "Rails s" it will work but not if you type "Rails s ".

It is consistent with which apps work and which apps do not work?

Comment: yes, it's consistent with the app. same results every time. If I make a new app the server runs fine. If I run "rails s" on an older app I get the server options list. same thing if I try "rails server".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I figured out the problem was created by deleting rails 4.0.0beta1 from my system. I still had version 3.2 installed but I think the deletion deleted the scripts folder as well. After typing

```
gem install rails
```

It worked again. Maybe this helps someone.